# Почему в методах React используют bind()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Начал осваивать `es6`, пишу на `ReactJs`. Встречаю в обработчиках событий методы типа:

```
onChange={this.selectKey.bind(this)}
```

Как нпример в [этом туториале](https://shoutinginfrench.com/setting-up-an-onchange-function-in-es6-react/)
Подскажите пожалуйста для чего используется `.bind(this)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) нужен, чтобы жестко задать, на что будет указывать this при вызове функции

Answer (score 1):

Еще можешь встретить такой вариант:

```
class App extends Component {

constructor(props) {
super(props);

this.selectKey = this.selectKey.bind(this);

}

render() {

    return (
        <div className="someClass">
            <input onChange={this.selectKey}/>
        </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Фактически, это тоже самое, что и твой вариант, с той лишь разницей, что тебе не придется писать .bind(this) везде, где нужно вызвать функцию.